# limit a string length by characters

Tags: php

Hi I have this piece of code and wanted to `echo "</dd>\n", chr(20);` with only 20 characters or whatever i choose.
Where am i going wrong?

Thanks

```
class newsStory{
    var $title="";
    var $link="";
    var $description="";
    var $pubdate="";

    function show(){
        if($this->title){
            if($this->link){
                echo "<dt><a href=\"$this->link\">$this->title</a></dt>\n";
            }elseif($this->title){
                echo "<dt>$this->title</a></dt>\n";
            }
            echo "<dd>";
            if($this->pubdate)
                echo "<i>$this->pubdate</i> - ";
            if($this->description)
                echo "$this->description";
            echo "</dd>\n", chr(20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What doesn't work? You should enclose all your `$this->property` inside `{}` within double-quoted strings:  `echo "<i>{$this->pubdate}</i> - ";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chr()` is used to display a character with the ASCII value given as the parameter. You're most likely looking to use `substr()` which will let you display part of the string (a substring).

```
$characterLimit = 20;
$the_string = "Whatever string it is you're wanting to display in a shortened version.";
echo "</dd>\n", substr($the_string, 0, $characterLimit);
```

should give you what you want.